# Environment variable value as RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule in place:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

For development purposes, environment variable APP_ENV = development is set in vhosts.conf

Is it possible to use the value of APP_ENV as a rewrite condition? I.e, I do not want anything redirected in the development environment.

I have tried the following, perhaps ignorantly?

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:APP_ENV} !^development
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you setting the environment variable? Things like mod_setenv and mod_rewrite occur at different points of the URL processing pipeline

Comment: It's set in vhosts using SetEnv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, `SetEnv` (mod_env) gets applied *after* mod_rewrite does, however, mod_setenvif gets applied *before*. This is what you need:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^ APPENV=development
```

in your vhost file. `SetEnv` won't set the value until after mod_rewrite has already been applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your environment variable right here in .htacccess:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^ APPENV=development

# then evaluate it in your rules further down
RewriteCond %{ENV:APPENV} !^development
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd rather avoid setting the var independently in htaccess. Can it not inherit the value from vhosts?

Comment: I would rather prefer having in .htaccess since changing it here doesn't require any server bounce but that is your call. I am not sure to get env variable value from vhost.